# How do i make 'active' navigation icon by hover or click?

Tags: css, nav

```
<div class="nav">
<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-info"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edu"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-employment"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-skills"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-photo"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-personality"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I wanted to make an image navigation bar with active and inactive mode. Active mode is on when hover over or clicked on. So i created the basic navigation list above, then added some CSS codes below.I have already get to the point where browser show all unactive icons by default.
I want to make a single page website, so all navigation icons here will link to a certain place within the page (im also trying to figure out how).

```
.icon-edu {background-image: url("./Img/Icon-edu.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.icon-edu: hover, 
.icon-edu: active {
background-image: url("./Img/Icon-edu-active.png");
}
```

So the problem is, i cannot get the active icon when i hover over the icon, or when they are active. I am not sure what else i need to do?
I am the most newbie-ish newbie, i started with Codecademy and went on making a website. Please take it easy on me :D

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp maybe you are missing this.

Comment: :active is more for link within same page and/or act as button.

Comment: i tried just now and it doesn't seem to work. I think my html code has some problems. I used the <i> class according to someone's question from stackoverflow.com, might have another way to put it.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to have some text in your i tags otherwise it's width will be 0px and you won't see anything (for icons you may want a div with fixed dimensions, but thats another problem) I used a background colour and some dummy text to get it working.

also your selectors don't connect to your a tags. so this will work.

```
    a:hover .icon-edu, 
    a:active .icon-edu {
        background-image: url("./Img/Icon-edu-active.png");
    }
```

for having an active state for a clicked link it's easiest to add another class to the link, in the code that generates the page. In your case you'll need to use jQuery which is a bit more complicated.

Comment: i fixed the problem with icon showing by using this CSS code:
[class^="icon-"] {
display: block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;

What i'm looking for is the active icon showing when i hover or click on the icon.

Comment: Is the hover change working? Changing the icon on click is a seperate problem. I would guess if you asked that seperately, someone else may already have a working solution.

Comment: also  `[class^="icon-"]` looks very hairy and could cause problems if you forget about it later on `.container ul i` is more specific.

Comment: I also tried your code above but no change found. ^_^!
The code a: hover ...

Also i'm sorry for my poor vocabulary. I edited the question to be: active instead of changing icon on click.
Sorry sorry :D

Comment: it should be `a:hover`, no space before hover. so if I follow you what you want is like what happens on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_active2 when you click on a link.